# Makefile with macro, does not generate any executable

Tags: c++, makefile

I wrote a Makefile(code below) for my program which contains hello.h, hello.cpp and main.cpp (this is a trivial testbench for hello.cpp).

However, after I type make in the terminal, it tells me

> make: `hello.o' is up to date.

Can someone give any hints? Thank you!

```
#MACRO
CAT_HOME = $(MGC_HOME)
TARGET = my_tb
#OBJECT1 = hello.o
OBJECTS = hello.o main.o
#OBJECT2 = main.o
DEPENDS = hello.cpp main.cpp hello.h
INCLUDES = -I"$(CAT_HOME)/shared/include"
DEFINES =
CXX = /usr/bin/g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -O3 $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES)

$(TARGETS) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS) : $(DEPENDS)

#phony target to remove all objects and executables
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: I see, that is terrible typo..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a `TARGET` variable but later try to use `$(TARGETS)`. Theres an S in difference.

Also, it is inefficient to let *every* .o file depend on *every* .cpp file. You might as well just write a linear script that recompiles everything unconditionally. Since you're depending on make's built-in rule for creating a .o from the corresponding .cpp, you don't need to declare that dependency explicitly. So you can remove all of the .cpp files from `DEPENDS` without losing any relevant dependencies.